# Finder reports error code -36 when copying some files

Tags: macos, mac, finder, hard-drive, error

I have a 4.6GB file on my hard drive. Today when I tried to copy it to another machine through network, I got the following error message from Finder halfway through the copy:

> The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in "(name of my file)" can't be read or written. (Error code -36)

In addition to copying that file to another machine through network, I also did the following:

- checked some other files on my hard drive and found another one with the same problem;
- tried copying those files to another folder **on the same hard drive**, and got the same error;
- tried to open one of those files, which was a .dmg file, by double clicking on its icon, and got a different message when Finder tried to verify it, saying there was an **input/output error**.

Then I tried the following to fix the problem:

1. Disk Utility: I ran Verify Disk and it said my disk is OK;
2. `fsck -fy`: it also said my disk is OK;
3. `dot_clean` as suggested [here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/02/21/fix-error-code-36-finder-mac-os-x/): didn't work, the error remained.

So what else can I try? Is this an indication that my hard drive is failing?

Comment: 'read or written' doesn't actually give any indication of which end of the transaction is failing. What is the format of the drive you are copying to, & over what mechanism? FAT32, for example, has a maximum file size of 4GB, FAT16 only 2GB.

Comment: I tried to copy the file again. Instead of copying to another machine, this time I copied it to a different folder on the same hard drive, and Finder showed the error again. So I don't think it's about FAT32 or FAT 16. Thanks for your suggestion anyway, I'll update my post.

Comment: So, are you saying that it could be the file that is damaged? Have you been able to open the files no problem?

Comment: @fabrice: Yes, it appears that the file is damaged. It is actually a dmg file. When I double click it, Finder tries to verify it, and fails the verification with an error message saying that there is an input/output error. Thanks! I'll update my post again.

Comment: Maybe Finder or destination drive's format are preventing you to copy a damaged file... Doesn't this solve it?

Comment: @fabrice: When the destination drive and the source drive are the same, I get the same error. As to the drive's format, I haven't formatted the hard drive since I bought the machine (a Mac mini), so it must be the original one. I think the files are indeed damaged, so what should I do now?

Comment: Place them in the trash? I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think damaged .dmg files can be salvaged. Also, they can be older .dmg files (OS X 10.1 for ex.) that are not recognized by recent systems, and often appear as damaged... If you get rid of the corrupted / obsolete files, I suppose transferring them isn't needed anymore?

Comment: @fabrice: I'm sure the .dmg file is very recent, so it should not be the problem. Because the files cannot even be copied, I think it's not that they contain bad data, but there's something wrong with the storage. I'm totally OK to give up that file because I can download it again. What I'm worrying is that my hard drive might be failing. Could it be developing bad sectors?

Comment: Your HDD is possibly going bad or at the least has some bad spots on its platters.  Neither Disk Utility or fsck preform the low-level testing of the entire disk to determine the actual physical state of the surface of all the platters in the HDD.